# What "regulatory purposes" would limit a launch test of a new vehicle to 50,000 feet?

Tags: launch, regulatory

The Art Technica article [Vector has completed the first successful flight test of its new micro rocket](https://arstechnica.com/science/2017/05/vector-barrels-ahead-with-its-small-satellite-launcher/) says:

> Vector Space Systems successfully launched a full-scale model of its Vector-R rocket on Wednesday in Mojave, California. The test flight, which remained under 50,000 feet for regulatory purposes, allows the company to remain on track to begin providing launch services for small satellites in 2018, said Jim Cantrell, the company’s chief executive and cofounder.

What regulatory purposes might these be?

**Bonus Question:** Why is the small-scale launch market like "shooting turkeys in a drum"? For that matter, what is shooting turkeys in a drum like to being with?

The Vector launch can be seen in this Tweet (lower your volume): https://twitter.com/jamesncantrell/status/859846383158689792

Comment: re turkeys in a drum: Cantrell was talking about getting paying customers (last 2 paragraphs in the article)

Comment: Jim Cantrell [never got is books back](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-books-that-Elon-Musk-used-to-self-study-rocket-science) from Elon Musk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vector flew their test at the [Friends of Amateur Rocketry](http://www.friendsofamateurrocketry.com) site, which has permits from the FAA to fly to 50,000 feet on weekends without obtaining additional permits per launch. For early tests of avionics and such, Vector can save time and money that way.

Comment: I see. http://www.friendsofamateurrocketry.org/SiteRequests.html